# Writing a file by a webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, path, asmx, streamwriter

I have a wevservice, and I would like to write logs into a textfile.

My problem is that i do not know what path to give when creating the streamwriter:

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("????");
```

Can you please help what path I should enter?

Comment: Where do you want to create the textfile?

Comment: preferably in the same location of the asmx file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you put it, you just need to give the web service the appropriate permissions to the location you want to write to. You can take a look at the Application pool to see which user you need to give the permissions, or you can use impersonation.

If you use `"MyLogfile.log"` it will be located in the same location as the web service, so a relative path will put it relative to that location. You can however use a absolute path too, like `"c:/log/MyLogfile.log`".

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

See [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(VS.90).aspx) and [this article on Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/createlogfiles.aspx)

**Update**: Here's an example is in order deploy on server and create a subdirectory for log files. You can test using your browser.

```xml
<%@ WebService Language="c#" Class="Soap"%>
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.IO;

[WebService]
public class Soap : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
    public bool Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        //NOTE: There are better ways of doing authentication. This is just illustrates Session usage.
        LogText("Login User = " + userName);
        UserName = userName;
        return true;
    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
    public void Logout()
    {    
        LogText("Logout User = " + UserName);
        Context.Session.Abandon();
    }

    private string UserName {
        get {return (string)Context.Session["User"];}
        set {Context.Session["User"] = value;}
    }

    private void LogText(string s) {
        string fname = Path.Combine(
            Server.MapPath( "/logs" ), "logfile.txt");
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fname);
        tw.Write("Yada yada :" + s);
        tw.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: MapPath converts a virtual path on the web server to a physical path that you need as an argument to StreamWriter  

So the whole physical path should be 
Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/myvirtualdir"), "logfile.txt");

Comment: i do not think that this work in a webservice .... I am getting an error that the method do not exist in the current context.

Comment: I am referring to "MapPath" in ( Path.Combine(Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.MapPath("/myvirtualdir"), "logfile.txt");

Comment: I am referring to the System.Web namespace. SQL Server has nothing to do with it